# Actionbar does not show items

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I know it has been asked several times before. But I guess I have to ask the question myself because none of the existing ones fits my problem:

I am developing for Kitkat(4.4) and try to use a action bar with the theme: holo.light.darkActionBar.

I created some xml files with the items in menu and linked it in the java class to the activity:

menu/main:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:title="@string/action_filter"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_filter"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The Problem is the following:
When I click on the menu/main.xml I can see that a item is added to the actionbar. But it never appears in the activity_main.xml.

I searched for many hours and considered the following:
-set minSDK to 19
-i know that some time it does not show up because the device has a menu button. But I use a icon and say it should be displayed. Therefore it should show up. And I also use a Nexus Emulation which has not menu button.
-I use Android studio and inserted the activities with the assistentce of android studio. 
-The mainActivity extends FragmentActivity(because I chose to have a google maps activity)
-I tried other themes but then the actionbar disappears totally(oc did not use .noActionBar!)
-I set a style for the actionbar and there I specify a red color. This color is propagated to the activity but not the items.

my imports are:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

How it should look:
[image: rendering the menu/main.xml]

How it looks rightnow:
[image: rendering the activity_main]

I really really hope some of you can help me, it drives me nuts.

Comment: Are you doing anything in one of your fragments that might be overriding the Activity's menu? You should also probably be using the new Toolbar instead: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Answer (score 1):

I think, your code to inflate the menu should look like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And remove `menu.clear()` line.

Comment: thank you for your answer. unfortunately it does not work. ps: my menu file name is main(but that does not really matter)

Comment: I changed that and the things CommonsWare told me and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

> try to use a action bar with the theme: holo.light.darkActionBar

That means that you are trying to use the native action bar.

> I created some xml files with the items in menu and linked it in the java class to the activity

Get rid of the `app` namespace, and rename `app:showAsAction` to be `android:showAsAction`. The `app` convention is used for the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport, which you are not using.

> MainActivity:

Get rid of `menu.clear()`.

> But it never appears in the activity_main.xml.

It is not supposed to. It should show up when you run the app, not necessarily in editors for other resources.

> And I also use a Nexus Emulation which has not menu button

There certainly were Nexus devices with MENU buttons. Try pressing <kbd>PgUp</kbd>; if you get the overflow menu rising from the bottom of the screen, your emulator has a MENU button.

Comment: I think thats going in the right direction:
I think android studio made the project compatible for older versions and therefore it uses appcompat.

Where can I specify wether I want the native action bar and not compiled with appcompat?

I tried to change it to android, but it says I should use app. I guess there is some place where it is set to appcompat.

Comment: @SeadiMove: "Where can I specify wether I want the native action bar and not compiled with appcompat?" -- remove `appcompat-v7` from the `dependencies` roster in your module's `build.gradle` file. Remove the `app` XML namespace from your menu resources and replace those `app` prefixes with `android`. Have your activity inherit from `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`. Have your theme (e.g., `res/values/styles.xml`) inherit from something other than an `AppCompat` theme. There may be a few other miscellaneous changes, but that will get you most of the way there.

Comment: Actually now it works. But does not show in the renderer. Thanks for your answer!

I would also like to know if i can configure that the app should not be compatible with very late versions. I already chose minSDK and targetSDK